# Vue router components evaluated on import

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have an application like

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './routes.es6';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  router,
}).$mount('#app');
```

`routes.es6` contains my router module:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Index from './pages/index.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'index',
    component: Index,
  },
  ...
];

export default new VueRouter({
  routes,
});
```

This works but has one major drawback. Let's assume my index component is defined as follows

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>
  require(...)

  export default {
    ...
  };
</script>
```

Now all `require` and `import` statements are evaluated once the components are imported in the `routes.es6` file and they are injected in the main app even though they should be scoped to the specific route.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called - **LAZY LOADING**

It is explained well in Vue-Router docs.
https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html